# Parsing non-well formed XML with Qt

Tags: xml, qt, qtxml

I'd like to use Qt to parse a non-well formed XML document of the form:

```
<log_data>
//lots of data
</log_data>
<log_data>
//more data
</log_data>

//etc.
```

Is this even possible or does the Qt XML parsing libraries absolutely require well-formed XML?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a skeleton document wrapper.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE wrapper [
<!ENTITY e SYSTEM "real.xml">
]>
<wrapper>&e;</wrapper>
```

where real.xml is the XML fragment you actually want to read; then point your XML parser at wrapper.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `<root>` before it and a `</root>` after it, and you have a valid XML document.

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't an option.  The file must be opened as read only and it's size prevents creating new well formed version of it.  That was my thought also though.

Comment: @Brad: Hm... Then you could implement a stream that reads from the file and returns it with the tag around it.

Comment: That's stream could be a custom QIODevice implementation wrapping the actual QFile.